# saving as csv corrupts dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of shape (455698, 62). I want to save it as a csv file, and load it again later with pandas. For now I do this :

```
df.to_csv("/path/to/file.csv",index=False,sep="\\", encoding='utf-8') #saving
df=pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv",delimiter="\\",encoding ='utf-8') #loading
```

and I get a dataframe with shape (455700, 62) : 2 more lines ? When I check in detail, (looking at all unique values in each columns), I found that some values changed columns in the process.

I've tried multiple separators, forcing dtype ="object", and I can't figure out where the bug is. What should I try?

Comment: You'll need to post raw data that reproduces this, also can you find what the extra columns are. You can save the initial columns as `first_cols = df.columns`, then load the df and compare `second_cols = other_df.columns` and then do `first_cols.difference(second_cols)`

Comment: a very very small glimpse of the data would be great to have an idea...

Comment: it's extra lines, not extra columns. I don't think I can post raw data, as it is very large and I don't have any idea where the issue could be (IMO it's only one or 2 lines which cause this issue)

Comment: Have you tried to do the same with `.to_json()` and `.read_json()`? Just to be sure that the file format isn't an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that some of your strings contain new-line (`\n`) character?

In this case i would suggest to use quoting when saving your CSV file:

```
import csv

df.to_csv("/path/to/file.csv",index=False,sep="\\", encoding='utf-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
...
```

Comment: I tried and it seems to work ! Thanks a lot, but can you explain ? I though pandas was already quoting values by default?

Comment: @HarryPotfleur, actually i'm bit confused - i tried to reproduce it and i failed to reproduce it using Pandas (version 0.19.2)

Comment: @HarryPotfleur, i mean i couldn't reproduce your issue with `+2` rows...

Comment: oh. I have no idea what caused the issue, but it works :)